# Android - entry nember

Tags: java, android

how would i go about adding an entry number at the start of a saved line of text to a .txt file. eg.

- 01, entry one
- 02, entry two
- 03, entry three

and so on

here is my code to write to the file

```
public void onClick(View v) {try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new       FileWriter("/sdcard/input_data.txt", true));
            out.write(txtData.getText() + "," + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
            out.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a counter field in your object, write its value each time an entry is written, and then increment it:

```
private int entryCounter = 1;

public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/input_data.txt", true));
        out.write(counter + ", " + txtData.getText() + "," + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        entryCounter++;
    ...
```

You should always close the writer in a finally block, to make sure it's closed even if some exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need to wrap the string to write into a reader and do a read and write per line.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(txtData.getText()));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/input_data.txt", true));

//... Loop as long as there is input.
int lineNumber = 0;
String line = null;
while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.write(lineNumber++ + ", " + line);
    writer.newLine();   // Write new line - "\n" on Android.
}

//... Close reader and writer.
reader.close();
writer.close();
```

Obviously you should put above code in a `try/catch` statement and close the reader and writer in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Change your onClick method to something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   Utils.appendLog(this, txtData.getText() + "," + dateFormat.format(new Date());
}
```

And create a Utils class with these methods:

```
public class Utils {
public static void appendLog(Context ctx, String text) {
        File logFile = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), Constants.YOUR_FILENAME);
        if (!logFile.exists()) {
           try {
              logFile.createNewFile();
           } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
        try {
            // BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
            BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
            buf.append(Utils.generateId(ctx) + "," + text);
            buf.newLine();
            buf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int generateId(Context ctx) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        int id = prefs.getInt("MyId", 1);
        Editor e = prefs.edit();
        e.putInt("MyId", id +1);
        e.commit();
        return id;
    }
}
```